# How to get a line whether cross a rectangle with javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I drew a line with 2 points,and there is a rectangle,I wanna get if it upon the line between the two point.

http://codepen.io/mrxf/pen/KNGeXB

[image]

I was tried to get the line's function ,then test if the rect's `left` and `top` add the `width` and `height` has any point on the line,but it is not a good idea for me.

Then I want to judge if the line cross the area,put the rect's `left` and `left+width` to the function,and get the `y` value,and compared with the rect's `top` and `top + height`

But I can't make it,it is difficule for me to convert this to the javascript function,so is there any way to get this?

Comment: Are you asking how to draw a rectangle so that it is on a line (which in the picture it *is*), or asking how to tell whether a given rectangle happens to be on a given line? (Or something else?) Perhaps you could [edit] your question to add the JS used to produce the above?

Comment: http://codepen.io/mrxf/pen/KNGeXB